# How do I grab the value from this SimpleXMLElement as a string in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

Say I have a variable called $myXMLElement and when I dump the variable it looks like this.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 7 ) 
    [0] => Kirkpatrick 
)
```

How do I grab the value of Kirkpatrick in PHP

Comment: what so hard with `[0] => Kirkpatrick`? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
(string) $var[0]
```

? Normally you do that with string casting, will turn SimpleXMLElements into the XML nodeValue.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the value:

```
echo $myXMLElement->{'0'};
```